# EF6 EntityValidationErrors when adding an entity with FK to an existing Entity (using only the id)

Tags: asp.net, sql, entity-framework, repository-pattern

I have the following scenario.

```
public class Company
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string AppId { get; set; }
    public string Token { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Document> Documents { get; set; }
}


public class Document
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public byte[] PdfBinary { get; set; }
    public string PdfFileName { get; set; }
    public int SignersCount { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }
    public int Pages { get; set; }

    public ICollection<TagDefinition> Tags { get; set; }

    public Document()
    {
        Company = new Entities.Company();
        Tags = new List<TagDefinition>();
    }
}
```

Now, here is the mapper or configuration file for both

```
public class CompanyMapper: EntityTypeConfiguration<Company>
{
    public CompanyMapper()
    {
        this.ToTable("Companies");

        this.HasKey(c => c.Id);
        this.Property(c => c.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        this.Property(c => c.Id).IsRequired();

        this.Property(c => c.Name).IsRequired();
        this.Property(c => c.AppId).IsRequired();
        this.Property(c => c.Token).IsRequired();
    }
}

 public class DocumentMapper: EntityTypeConfiguration<Document>
{
    public DocumentMapper()
    {
        this.ToTable("Documents");

        this.HasKey(c => c.Id);
        this.Property(c => c.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        this.Property(c => c.Id).IsRequired();

        this.Property(c => c.Name).IsRequired();
        this.Property(c => c.Name).HasMaxLength(255);

        this.Property(c => c.Pages).IsOptional();

        this.Property(c => c.SignersCount).IsRequired();

        this.Property(c => c.PdfBinary).IsRequired();
        this.Property(c => c.PdfBinary).IsMaxLength();

        this.Property(c => c.PdfFileName).IsRequired();

        HasRequired(c => c.Company).WithMany(c => c.Documents).HasForeignKey(c => c.CompanyId);
    }
}
```

HERE IS THE PROBLEM. (See code below this explanation)

I want to create a new Document... so, when I try to add a new Document to my database and only set CompanyId (not the whole Company instance), I get the following error...

```
Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.
```

When I look at the GetValidationErrors() collection, it's basically telling me that the fields for Company are empty (they are marked as required in the dabatase). So, it seems like is trying to create a new record for Company id=1... which is odd because it already exists. I am so confused about how this EF6 works. It was my understanding that by setting a ComapanyId property in my Document object, then map it using the Configuration file, was enough to make an INSERT work as expected. Now if I pass to Document the whole Company Entity, then it works as expected.

Isn't CompanyId enough infomation for EF to know that it belongs to a record in Companies table with id = 1?

```
var doc = new Document(){ Name = "Name",
        PdfFileName = "Filename",
        CompanyId = 1};
        _repo.Create(doc);
```

Here is the Repository...

```
public abstract class WriteRepository<TContext> : IWriteRepository where TContext : DbContext, new()
{
    private readonly TContext _context;

    protected TContext Context { get { return _context; } }

    protected WriteRepository()
    {
        _context = new TContext();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _context.Dispose();
    }

    ...

    public TItem Create<TItem>(TItem item, bool saveImmediately = true) where TItem : class, new()
    {
        return PerformAction(item, EntityState.Added, saveImmediately);
    }

    protected virtual TItem PerformAction<TItem>(TItem item, EntityState entityState, bool saveImmediately = true) where TItem : class, new()
    {
        _context.Entry(item).State = entityState;
        if (saveImmediately)
        {
            try
            {
                _context.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var x = _context.GetValidationErrors();
            }
        }
        return item;
    }
```

Seems to me very odd that if I have a valid ID for a FK, I still have to pass the whole Company instance to the document instance. I have tried to find documentation about it. I find examples similar to mine that seems to work for them, but not for me :(

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shouldn't have to set your own EntityState. EF should track that for you if you model your relationships correctly.

Your best bet is to treat Company like an aggregate route. Then let it deal with setting up the relationships. Something like this would be a good starting point:

```
var company = companySet.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 1);

var newDoc = new Document()
{                
    Name = "foo doc",
    Pages = 1,
    SignersCount = 0,
    PdfBinary = new byte[]{},
    PdfFileName = "foo.pdf"
};

company.AddDocument(newDoc);
```

Then in the Company class:

```
public void AddDocument(Document document)
{
    document.Company = this;
    Documents.Add(document);
}
```

The key here is that you need to add the document to the Companies document collection to save the relational data correctly.

Then you just need to call SaveChanges on your DbContext.  How you do this is up to you. You'll probably have to play around with your Repository design a bit.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I disagree thou. I am very aware of DDD. Just because an Entity feels "natural" as a parent of another entity, it shouldn't be enough reason to load the whole Graph to save a child entity. Document in its own is an Aggregate Root. Just because a City object "feels" like a child of State object and so on up to Universe object, doesn't mean you need to load the Universe to save the City. Even between AR is good practice to only reference each other via ID. But anyway, i will look into the EntityState. i am new to EF... NHibernate was my ORM of choice.

Comment: I think it depends on how you're interacting with entities in the system. I did make an assumption that Documents are created within the context of a company, that was a mistake on my part.